# Chromatic polynomial of a cycle - Interpreting its terms

Tags: graphs

I am learning about graph coloring. One of the exercise problems(grimaldi) led me to derive the chromatic polynomial for any cycle($C_n, n \ge 3$).

$P(C_n, \lambda) = (\lambda - 1)^n + (-1)^n(\lambda - 1)$, where $\lambda$ is the number of colours available

Is it possible to interpret the terms of above polynomial? I need help doing the same.

Comment: Is it ok If I ask the same question on math.stackexchange.com? I found a related question [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91009/prove-that-the-chromatic-polynomial-of-a-cycle-graph-c-n-equals-k-1n)

Comment: Please wait a few days to give people here the change to answer. Alternatively, you can request your question be migrated to [math.SE].

Answer (score 2):

There is a theorem of Whitney answering your question. Let
$$ P(G,\lambda) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k a_k \lambda^{n-k}. $$
Then $a_k$ is the number of $k$-subsets of the edges of $G$ not containing any *broken cycle*. A broken cycle of $G$ is obtained from a cycle of $G$ by removing its maximum edge according to some fixed ordering of the edges.

For example, if $G = C_n$ then for $k < n-1$, $a_k = \binom{n}{k}$, and $a_{n-1} = \binom{n}{n-1} - 1$, since we miss one broken cycle.

For a proof and references to other proofs, see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.1182).